# Sed - grab html tags that have a pattern match inbetween

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I want to use bash tools to grab content between tags, but only if a pattern matches somewhere inbetween.

For example, If I have this file:

```
<tag>
CAT
</tag>

...

<tag>
DOG
HORSE
</tag>

...
<tag>
DOG
CAT
</tag>
```

I want the output to be:

```
<tag>
CAT
</tag>
<tag>
DOG
CAT
</tag>
```

I can use sed to print the contents of opening and closing tags `cat file.txt | sed -n '/<tag/,/<\/tag/p'`, but how do I filter "each block" based on whether they have the word "CAT" on at least one line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if that can be done by `sed`.But if you are willing to use `perl`(bash tool) you can go ahead with this regex.

```
(<tag>(?=(?:(?!<\/tag>).)*CAT)(?:(?!<\/tag>).)*<\/tag>)
```

Just grab the captures.Do not forget to add flags `s` and `g`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/aW3pR4/8